# Updated. Triple-BOOT: Windows 7/8 and Ubuntu (7/8 already installed)

Tags: dual-boot

Scroll down and read my update please

I have Windows 7 and 8.1 installed and i want to install ubuntu.

My windows 7 is 32bit, windows 8.1 is 64bit(my printer driver is not released on 64bit, but my job requires 64bit). I want to tripleboot 3OS-es. My downloaded ubuntu is amd64.

Installed Ubuntu 14.04

Wanted to disable GRUB(Windows Recovery Environment(on/dev1/sda) to boot windows 7/8;
or Ubuntu to boot to Ubuntu)

I tried EasyBCD:

1. i open EasyBCD clicked on 'add new entry'
2. Chose Linux and chose GRUB and GRUB2
3. clicked on 'BCD Deployment' chose ...vista/7... and 'Write MBR'
4. Rebooted
5. GRUB was not showing (Gone to the windows boot recovery)BUT........
6. There were showing only windows 7/8.1

How to make 3 booting scenes in the 'boot recovery

Update:  Made 3 booting scenes but when i choose Ubuntu it goes into black screen and says failed to load kernel what to do?

Comment: Just some additional information, Having Windows (No matter what version) is still considered one booting system. Inside the Windows boot manager, both are handled as the same, you only choose which one you want when you are already inside the Windows boot system. In your case you are actually Dual Booting (Ubuntu / Windows). If you choose Windows then you are shown the Windows boot manager which would show Windows 7 / 8. Triple booting would be something like Mac / Windows / Ubuntu (FreeBSD, Microsoft, Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some people have had success adding Linux using tools such as EasyBCD, this has never worked for me. I recommend using grub as your boot loader.

If you're willing to try grub, which should give you a menu at startup to choose between the 3 OS, boot Ubuntu from your Live Media and try using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 0):

Having Windows (No matter what version) is still considered one booting system. Inside the Windows boot manager, both are handled as the same, you only choose which one you want when you are already inside the Windows boot system. In your case you are actually Dual Booting (Ubuntu / Windows). If you choose Windows then you are shown the Windows boot manager which would show Windows 7 / 8. Triple booting would be something like Mac / Windows / Ubuntu (FreeBSD, Microsoft, Linux).

In your particular case I would NOT recommend disabling GRUB, since this would be the only boot manager in your case that can handle both, Windows versions and Ubuntu. The Windows manager still has many problems handling Non-Microsoft OSes and your boot section of Linux would be bound to Windows, so any failure (eg: Viruses attacking the boot manager) will also affect if you can boot Ubuntu or not (If the Windows boot manager fails, everything fails).

I recommend doing the following, since you have all 3 already installed, try to run the grub updater to see if it can show all 3 OSes on the same boot screen:

```
 sudo update-grub
```